# I changed a python file in docker container but it's not taking effect (print not working)

Tags: python, docker, pytorch

**Main issue** : print commands in python code files not showing up.

Apart from restarting the docker image, do I need to do something else ?
The application is a python machine learning model.

Here are the detailed steps of what I did:

- I have a logged into the docker container using the below command - **docker exec -u 0 -it abx /bin/bash**
- Changed a file. I put some print commands in it, just to make sure
  they show up before I make any bigger change.
- Restarted the docker container using **docker stop abx** & then **docker start abx**
- I'm checking the logs by doing **docker logs abx**

What am I missing.. ?

Comment: When you stop the container, does the print output show in the logs?

Comment: Anything you change with `docker exec` will be changed as soon as you `docker rm` the container: this approach is inevitably going to lose work.  Can you do most development in a non-Docker virtual environment instead, running `docker build` when you need to update the image for integration testing?

Comment: @BMitch - it does show after it is stopped !! How do I make it without having to keep restarting ?

Comment: That's stdout buffering, which is the default with python. See the linked solution which should handle your issue.